# Getting the values and column names of an INSERT object in the Java Cassandra Driver

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I have a Insert object created as follows:

```
Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("demo", "users");
insert.value("name", name);
insert.value("sport", "test");
insert.value("years", 2);
insert.value("vegetarian", true);
```

Somewhere else in my code, I need to get the list of names and values associated with this INSERT object. When I debug the code I can see two "values" and "names" ArrayLists that contain the information I need, however they are private and I cannot access them.

While `insert.getObject(0);` gets the object from the values ArrayList, I can't map the value to a column name. Furthermore `insert.getValues(ProtocolVersion.V4, CodecRegistry.DEFAULT_INSTANCE);` seems to serialize the objects and put them into a ByteBuffer which is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/PreparedStatement.html) & [BoundStatement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/BoundStatement.html) instead of simple `Insert`.  First, you can get better performance if you're inserting a lot of data. And second - you'll be able to get a list of variables defined in prepared statement, together with associated values